# Is there any red black tree or avl tree implementation in c++ standard library?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, avl-tree, red-black-tree

Just like multiset is a Binary Search Tree implementation in STL, is there any RB tree or AVL tree implementation available?

Comment: std::map is a red/black tree. The standard doesn't say it must be one, but the performance guarantees make it unlikely that something else would be used.

Comment: Pretty sure that most standard library implementations use RB trees for all four of (multi)set|map. The standard doesn't specify the implementation though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you would not implement a `multiset` as a binary search tree.  Using one would break the performance guarantees of the standard as the tree could wind up looking like a linked list which does not have O(logN) insert and removals.

Typically `std::set`/`std::multiset`/`std::map`/`std::multimap` are implemented as a RB tree as it has those performance guarantees.  This is not required though.  The standard only guarantees the performance of the container in different operations and it is up to the implementation how to achieve that.

If you want to guarantee you are using an RB tree you either need to check your implementation, roll your own, or get a third party library that guarantees it is a RB tree.

Comment: A red-black tree is a binary tree. A balanced binary tree.

Answer (score 1):

From what I was told on my post is No, there is not a standard C++ library yet for Red-Black Trees as of today, January 10th, 2022.

Comment: But I can give out a red black tree function that can be available for everyone to use.

Comment: `std::map` is implemented as a red-black tree, no?

Answer (score -2):

**std::map is a sorted associative container that contains key-value pairs with unique keys. Keys are sorted by using the comparison function Compare. Search, removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity. Maps are usually implemented as Red–black trees**
*https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map*

Comment: AI generated? Why shout so much?